# Filter out words with Notepad++?

Tags: filter, notepad++

Lets say I have a text file with 100,000 words (text file A), and text file with 500 words (text file B). How would I filter text file A for words in text file B

Eg If the word is in both A and B, remove the word from A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *have* to use Notepad++ ? If not, you can use Cygwin/Unix utilities and do this:

```
grep -v -f text_file_b text_file_a
```

This matches words from `text_file_b` (**-f**) against `text_file_a` and prints those that *don't* match (**-v**)

I appreciate this doesn't use Notepad++, but I would advocate using the right tools for the right job, and I'm not sure an interactive editor is what you want here.

Comment: I dont have to use it, but it is preferred. I'll try out Cygwin!